# What effect does the parity of the rank have on the eigenvalues?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

> Let $A \in M_n (\mathbb{R})$ be a real matrix of odd rank $n$. Prove that there exists $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $$\mbox{Rank} (A - \lambda I) < n$$

---

I am trying to prove this statement, yet I don't seem to find any information I can deduct from the given information. All I could deduct from the information that $n$ is odd is that the characteristic polynomial is of rank $n$, therefore has an odd (maximal) rank.

Comment: every polynomial with odd degree has a real root

Comment: I see, what does this tell us about polynomials with an even degree?
And how does the fact that $A$'s characteristic polynomial has a real root help us prove the statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every polynomial with odd degree has a real root, as Alan pointed out. In other words, the matrix $A$ has an eigenvalue $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$. Let $v$ be a corresponding eigenvector, then for this eigenvector we have $(A-\lambda I) v =0$. By the definition of an eigenvector, $v \neq 0$. Hence $ \dim \text{Null} (A-\lambda I) >0$.

What does this tell you about  $\text{Rank} (A-\lambda I)$? Hint: you can use [the Fundamental Theorem of Linear Maps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem).

---

*Additional information*

For a matrix $A \in \mathbb{R^{n \times n}}$ it holds that

$$A \text{ nonsingular} \iff \text{rank} A=n \iff \text{Null }A= \{0\}$$

In the present case, we have shown for the matrix $B=A-\lambda I$, that it has a nontrivial solution (there exists a vector $v \neq 0$ such that $Bv=0$), that is, $\text{Null} B\neq \{ 0\}$ . Thus from the above equivalence we can conclude $\text{rank} B \neq n$, since $\text{rank} B \leq n$, we conclude $\text{rank} B<n$.

And in addition we can conclude that $B$ is singular (it is not non-singular).

Comment: If I understood your question correctly, since $Rank(Ker(A-\lambda I))>0$ and $Rank(A)=n$ this means that $Rank(Im(A-\lambda I))<n $ which means that $Rank(A-\lambda I)<n$?

Comment: Exactly! Except I would use $dim$ instead of $Rank$ when you are talking about the $Im$ and the $Ker$.

Comment: Thank you for the assistance and guidance!
When looking at the solution provided by my lecturer, he claims that since exists an eigenvector $v\neq 0$ such that $(A-\lambda I)\cdot v = 0$ , there exists a non-trivial solution for the homogeneous system( of equations) which means that $A-\lambda I$ is singular and therefor $rank(A-\lambda I)<n$ . this explanation is really confusing and I cant see the logic in it, think you could explain/elaborate on the transitions done there, in case you know?

Comment: A fact that is important to know is that for a square matrix $A$ it holds that $A$ is invertible iff A has full rank iff the homogenous system $Ax=0$ only has the trivial solution

Comment: Note that singular is another word for "not invertible"

Comment: I have edited my answer @Aishgadol

Comment: The way you explained this in your edited comment is astonishing. really helped me understand, I greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Very happy that it helped you!